# Dark Souls Prepare to die edition has trouble starting

Tags: dark-souls

This seems to be a new issue because I can't find anything on the web that helps me out. I recently got a new computer and decided to download Dark Souls on it (The first one). It installed perfectly fine, no bumps or anything. Load the game, says performing first time set up and goes away relatively quickly. Game launches in windowed mode and only shows a white screen. Everything else works fine on my computer. It doesn't seem like the application is not responding because the "X" to close the window responded instantly. I tried to run it through the beta mode because that is how it ran successfully on my old computer. I tried to find some settings to maybe get it out of windowed mode but no luck (Couldn't find the file). [image: How dark souls loads.]

Comment: Update: It's been on for a couple minutes now and nothing changed

Comment: Are you using DSFix? If not, you should be. It fixes weird graphical stuff in DS1 (and generally makes it playable on PC), so installing it may help.

Comment: @pushasha Link?

Comment: [Here's the link](http://www.nexusmods.com/darksouls/mods/19/?). Make sure to read the installation instructions!

Comment: @pushasha Only thing that chaged after installation is that now it starts in fullscreen

Comment: Is this on a laptop by any chance?

Comment: @pushasha Yes, my previous computer was also a laptop and worked fine in the beta version

Comment: It depends on the graphics setup the laptop has, so this laptop may have a different card. Try following the steps in [this comment](https://steamcommunity.com/app/211420/discussions/0/458604254424261804/#c458604254424888793), and see if that helps.

Comment: With this kind of problem, updating the graphic card drivers and completely reinstalling the game can never hurt. (well, ok, I mean, very very very very very very very very rarely updating GPU drivers can brick the card, but that's like 8 very's)

Comment: @pushasha IT WORKED! Thank you. I suggest you post it as an answer so that you can get some sweet rep

Comment: Yay! Glad to hear it! Will do :)

Comment: @Dallium I tried both things. The problem has been resolved already but thanks for the input :) ALways helps

Comment: @pushasha Even though it is solved. Dark Souls still has the shittiest pc port known to man

Comment: @BakedPotato Yeah, it's pretty awful. DSFix helped fix a lot of the issues I had with it, but even with that it's still icky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running the game on a laptop with an integrated graphics card, try the following steps (taken from Steam user Iro's comment [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/211420/discussions/0/458604254424261804/#c458604254424888793)):

1. Right-click on your desktop, then open NVIDIA Control Panel
2. Head to "Manage 3D Settings" > Program Settings > Select Dark Souls (darksouls.exe), or add it if it isn't there.
3. Select the preferred graphics processor for the program: "Integrated Graphics"
4. Launch the game -- it should start properly now.
5. In the menu PC Settings, change it to Fullscreen and select your resolution
6. Quit the game
7. Open NVIDIA Control Panel again and this time select High-performance NVIDIA Processor

The game should now run as expected!

Comment: +1 because I'm pretty sure you saw the laptop battery logo in the bottom right on the users explorer bar and deduced everything from there. Well done Sherlock, well done indeed.